# How to declare variable names dynamically in java script?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-variables

I have an array:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I need to declare within a for loop, variables value_x- when x is each one of the array value.

what I've tried:

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    var x = 'hello there';
    var str = 'var ' + `value_${arr[i]}` + ' = ' + "'" + x + "'" + ';'
    eval(str);
}
```

now, str =

```
var value_a = 'hello there';
```

but the eval() call return this error:

```
error: EvalError: Dynamic code evaluation disallowed‏
```

now, I saw also solution which used window object, like:

```
window[`value_${arr[i]}`] = x;
```

and this also return error:

`error: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

which because this is local script, not on the server.
please help.‏
‏

```
    ‏
```

Comment: You don't need dynamically created variable names, use a proper data structure, an array or an object, instead.

Comment: no, I do need dynamically created variable names. in fact I have dozens of names I want to declare in same logic.

Comment: You cannot do that, so you need a Plan B.  If you use an object, you can create property names dynamically. (Yes, you can create properties on the global object context, but that's asking for trouble.)

Comment: This seems like a bad solution to whatever your actual problem is.

Comment: @rikir — Whatever XY problem you have, dynamic variable names are the worst possible solution for it. Use an object.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a concept for dynamically created variable names like some other languages have, you've to rethink your logic.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks for you advice. can you please refer me to example for dinamically object properties names?

Comment: @rikir `obj[keyIsVariable] = valueIsVariable`

Comment: @rikir — See the duplicate question.

Comment: Your problem solving via dynamic variables is not a good solution. The wrong design always leads to a difficult solution. My recommendation is to use other data structures such as Array or Object.